# THREE JS shape combined

Tags: react-three-fiber

[The result shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/

```
const Board = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <group {...props}>
        <mesh scale={[2, 3, 0.1]}>
          <boxGeometry />
          <meshStandardMaterial />
        </mesh>
        <mesh scale={[4, 3, 0.1]}>
          <cylinderGeometry />
          <meshStandardMaterial />
        </mesh>
      </group>
    </>
  );
};
```

GhkKp.png)

i was expecting a box and a cylinder.

Comment: i am getting a shape like a box with it's ends bent into a sharp edge